# My setter doesn't work in new class (inheritance)

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is my code. I created base class and in constructor set x=0. Next I used `virtual set_x() = 0`. And I created set_x() in new class. Output:

`set x` 
`100`
`DONE. Let's check.  0500`

Why I got 0500 not 100500?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct invalid_file_handler : std::runtime_error{
    using runtime_error::runtime_error;
};
class base_class{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    virtual void set_x()=0;
    void set_y(){
        this->y=500;
    }
    int get_x(){
        return (this->x);
    }
    int get_y(){
        return (this->y);
    }
    base_class(){
      this->x=0;
      this->y=0;
    }
};

class new_class :public base_class{
public:
    void set_x();
private:
    int z;
    int x;
    int y;
};

void new_class::set_x(){
    cout << "set x " << endl;
    this->x=100;
    cout << this->x << endl << "DONE. Let's check.  ";
}

int main()
{

    ifstream my_open_file;
    string file_path = "/home/wojtek/Pulpit/elo.odt";
    try{
        my_open_file.open("/home/wojtek/Pulpit/elo.odt");
        my_open_file.close();
    }catch (std::runtime_error &e){
        cerr << "Hello Xd XD chua" << endl;
        cerr << e.what();
    }
    ofstream myfile;
    try{
    myfile.open ("/home/wojtek/Pulpit/example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
    }
    catch(invalid_file_handler &e){
        cerr << "Hello!" << endl;
    }
    new_class *object = new new_class();
    object->set_x();
    cout << object->get_x();
    object->set_y();
    cout << object->get_y();
    //base_class object;
    //cout << object.get_y();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't declare `x` in the child class.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp then it would not compile

Comment: @Slava I didn't notice it was `private`. OP could change that to `protected`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I forgot about it. :P

Comment: I think I need a little break xD

Answer (score 1):

The variables `x` and `y` declared in `new_class` are *shadowing* the variables with the same names declared in `base_class`. This means that in any member method of `new_class`, the name `x` refers to `new_class::x` and **not** `base_class::x`.

Simply remove these lines from the `new_class` definition:

```
int x;
int y;
```

And make the same members in the `base_class` `protected` instead of `private` so that the `new_class` also has access:

```
class base_class{
protected:
    int x;
    int y;
```

---

Note: your code has a memory leak, since you never `delete object` after allocating it. Always `delete` what you `new`, and don't use `new` unless you really need to.